# Selenium with keyword + data driven framework is better or Page Object Model

Tags: selenium, keyword, pageobjects

I developed a framework using Keyword (Keywords driven from excel so its data driven as well) and used TestNG features as well. For Locators, I am using Properties file. This works fine for me and able to maintain, add, delete, modify new test cases as well. In addition to this, I am able to Skip a step or Proceed to another step even if a step has failed, stop execution of a test case if a step has failed and move to another test case, selective execution of test case as well, take screenshot as per user requires (not just if test step has failed). I am kind of so convinced with this framework.

My question is why people follow page object model more than these frameworks which work so well and simple to use?

Answer (score 1):

It depends, that what fits best for someone.

As you mentioned that **you** are kind of convinced with the existing framework because it does most of the stuff that is required from a web automation framework. So you can continue with the same.

Generally a framework should be designed in such a way that is easy to:

- understand
- adapt
- maintain and change
- grow
- lightweight

for it's creator and users. Obviously not only for it's developer.

Now to answer your question, if existing framework is capable enough of doing mentioned features flawlessly and users of framework are also kind of convinced with this framework and doing automation rapidly with ease. Then you are good.

Data driven - data you need in both case, whether you use properties files or POM. So it comes down to Properties files v/s page object model.

**Properties files**

- Easy to understand (by users of framework)
- Reduces code stuff (some automation testers prefer to have less code, not always true)
- Framework should provide a way to load files and fetch the locators
- What if size of project grows, need more files, loading more file consumes more memory.
- Creates confusion if files are not categorized properly

**Page Object Model**

- Might be a bit tricky to understand by users(not always true)
- Adds more code stuff
- It's flexible (can grow and shrink smoothly)
- Consumes less memory as compare to properties files
- And yes power of **encapsulation**

---

So as a conclusion, there is a trade-off between usability of the framework v\s adaptability of the framework. Understand the size and complexity of the project and users of the framework. You will find out best suitable framework architecture.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. 1. Advantage of POM (It's flexible - Can grow and shrink smoothly). Lets take an example of a step in test case which is 'AddEmployee'. This step has lot of fields to be entered (Say for example, enter data in 10 textbox). In POM, one would write a method addEmployee which would take 10 inputs and enter data in all the 10 textbox and click on add. So we have just one method. So all the test cases which needs this step can call this method and so its reusable. After few days, if there is an addition/removal of a field, then i just need to change addEmployee method.

Comment: The above thing can be achieved via excel keyword driven as well and pass the 10 inputs from the same excel. so technically, we are reducing a lot of code via keyword when compared to POM. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: I've used both and highly prefer POM now.  It's faster, easier to read, LESS code in my experience, and you don't have to go look up key values - the functions are all contained within the page object.  It also makes sense for me to have the locators in the same file as the page object itself.  For anything beyond a "hello world" script, I will always use a POM.

Comment: @user2356679 nope, you are not missing anything. As I already metioned both way job can be done. Yes it is very easy to add one more field in excel and you're good with the new change. But see the other side as size of project will increase, more excels, more keys, loading into heap, reading and then entering the data in text-box. In case of POM it's all in front of your eyes and with small understanding of programming it can be changed easily. POM - What can be done on any page is completely contained by page object at one place. Again it's a choice on the basis of time, team and project.